# Trait implementation of io::Read on new type

Tags: arrays, rust

I have implemented a struct inside a module. I am trying to implement the io::Read trait for a reference slice of the struct.

Here is a simplified version of my code. For now the new trait implementation is inefficient. I am trying different things to make it work.

```
struct mytype {
    inner: f32,
}
impl io::Read for mytype {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        buf.write_u32::<LittleEndian>(self.inner.to_bits()).unwrap();
        Ok(4)
    }
}    
impl<'a> io::Read for &'a [mytype] {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut vec8: Vec<u8> = vec![];
        for t in self.iter() {
            match (*t).read_u32::<LittleEndian>() {
                Ok(u) => vec8.write_u32::<LittleEndian>(u).unwrap(),
                Err(x) => (),
            }
        }
        for (ind, it) in vec8.iter().enumerate() {
            buf[ind] = *it;
        }
        Ok(vec8.len())
    }
}
```

The rust compiler keeps complaining about the code with this error:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> src\lib.rs:37:1
   |
37 | impl<'a> io::Read for &'a [mytype] {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
   |
   = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Just implementing io::Read for `mytype` works correctly.

Comment: Since you are not the owner of the slice type `&[T]`, you cannot implement `io::Read` for it. Creating your own type around a slice might be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Moreover, you are advised to checkout [Rust's naming guidelines](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html). Struct names should be in UpperCamelCase (so: `MyType`).